# Show $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a common Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, independence

Anyone has any idea about the following question?

> Let $\Bbb E(X_1^2)$ and $\Bbb E(X_2^2)$ be finite. Show that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and likewise $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$, then both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a common Gaussian distribution.

There is a hint that "$2x_1 = 2x_1-x_2+x_2$ and $2x_2=2x_2-x_1+x_1$ and then apply central limit theorem four times", but I still have no idea how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: central limit theorem for a finite number of random variables?

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks. But we don't know how $X_1,X_2$ are distributed. We just know they are independent.

Comment: I see ... I will delete the comment.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\phi_1(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_1})$ and $\phi_2(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_2})$ be the characteristic functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively.

Since $2X_1=(X_1+X_2)+(X_1-X_2)$ we conclude by independence that
$$\phi_1(2t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{it(X_1+X_2)})\mathbb{E}(e^{it(X_1-X_2)})=
\mathbb{E}(e^{it X_1 })\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_2})\mathbb{E}(e^{it X_1})
\mathbb{E}(e^{-itX_2})
$$
That is
$$\phi_1(2t)=\phi_1^2(t)\vert \phi_2(t)\vert^2\tag{1}
$$
and similarly, Since $2X_2=(X_1+X_2)-(X_1-X_2)$ we get
$$\phi_2(2t)=\phi_2^2(t)\vert \phi_1(t)\vert^2\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that $\vert\phi_1(2t)\vert =\vert \phi_2(2t)\vert$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and consequently 
$$\forall\,t\in \mathbb{R},\qquad \vert\phi_1(t)\vert =\vert \phi_2(t)\vert\tag{3}$$
Thus $$\vert\phi_k(t)\vert=\vert\phi_k(\frac{t}{2})\vert^4,\quad\hbox{ for  $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and $k=1,2$}.\tag{4}$$

- If $X_1$ is constant then $\vert\phi_1(t)\vert\equiv1$ and from $(3)$ we get
  $\vert\phi_2(t)\vert\equiv1$ and consequently $X_2$ is also constant. The converse is also true. So, we get the trivial solution where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are constant random variables.
- So let us suppose that $X_1$ is not a constant random variable. So
  Now, Since $X_1$ is square integrable, then,  in the neighborhood of $~0$, we have $$\phi_1(t)=1+i\mu_1 t+\frac{s_1^2}{2}t^2 +o(t^2)$$ where $\mu_1=\mathbb{E}(X_1)$ and $s_1^2=\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)$. 
  From $(4)$ we have
  $$\vert\phi_1(t)\vert=\left\vert\phi_1\left(t2^{-n}\right)\right\vert^{4^n}=\left\vert\left(1+i\frac{\mu_1t}{2^n}-\frac{s_1^2t^2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}+o(4^{-n})\right)^{4^n}\right\vert$$
  Taking the limit as $n$ tend to $+\infty$ we see that, 
  $$\forall\,t\in\mathbb{R},\qquad\vert\phi_1(t)\vert=e^{-\sigma_1^2t^2/2}$$
  where $\sigma_1^2=s_1^2-\mu_1^2$. by $(3)$ we see that 
  $$\forall\,t\in\mathbb{R},\qquad\vert\phi_2(t)\vert=e^{-\sigma_1^2t^2/2}$$ 
  In particular ${\rm var}(X_2)={\rm var}(X_1)=\sigma_1^2=\sigma^2$.

Going back to $(1)$ we see that for every $t$ and $n$ we have
$$\phi_1(t)=\left(\phi_1\left(\frac{t}{2^n}\right)\right)^{2^n}e^{-\sigma^2(1-2^{-n})t^2/2}$$
taking the limit as $n$ tends to $+\infty$ we get $\phi_1(t)=e^{i\mu_1 t-\sigma^2t^2/2}$, and similarly we obtain   $\phi_2(t)=e^{i\mu_2 t-\sigma^2t^2/2}$.
So, both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Gaussian variables, **with the same variance**.

**Conversely**, If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent Gaussian variables with the same variance then
$${\rm cov}(X_1-X_2,X_1+X_2)=\mathbb{E}(X_1^2-X_2^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X_1-X_2)
\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2)={\rm var}(X_1)-{\rm var}(X_2)=0$$
and consequently, the are independent.
(This is only true for Gaussian variables).

Comment: Brilliant. So how many times did you use CLT?

Comment: @BCLC, the  method of proof of CLT was used 4 times, but this is not part of the question, and not part of the answer.  When a hint is given, it is to help you find the idea of the solution, but it is not something that you "must" use, unless it is a part of the question.

Comment: Omran Kouba, I was just wondering. Where in the proof are the times where you used CLT?

Answer (score 4):

This result (without the assumption of finite second moments) is due to Mark Kac:  [*On a characterization of the normal distribution*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371328?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), dating to 1939. *When $X_1$ and $X_2$ are symmetric*, the approach hinted at in your question leads one to show that, for $n=1,2,\ldots$, the random variable $X_1$ has the same distribution as
$$
{X_{n,1}+X_{n,2}+\cdots+X_{n,2^n}\over 2^{n/2}}
$$
(where the $X_{n,k}$ are iid with the same distribution as $X_1$),
following which the CLT shows that $X_1\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ for $\sigma^2=\Bbb E[X_1^2]$. Likewise for $X_2$.

Kac then relates an argument of A. Wintner showing how to remove the symmetry assumption, using a (non-trivial) theorem of H. Cramér (which states that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables such that $X+Y$  is normally distributed, then both $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed).  It would be quite interesting if a direct CLT argument could be made, bypassing Cramér's result.

Comment: And upon refreshing my screen, I see that @OmranKouba has done just that.

Comment: Sooo cmiiw, but this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: What are $X_{n,1}, X_{n, 2}, \ldots X_{n,2^n}$ ? i.i.d. copies of $X_1$?

Comment: @BCLC: The question  ("Anyone has any idea about the following question?") was a little vague, but my reply certainly answers it; admittedly my use-of-CLT-count is off by 2.

Comment: Okay then. +1 ^-^

Comment: Could you please explain how does CLT implies that $X_1$ is normal distributed? I cannot see where did you use the assumption that $X_1 +X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are independent. If we assume that $X_1$ is symmetric and has distribution different than normal, and we take a sequence of i.i.d copies of $X_1$, and by CTG the averaged sum will converge in distribution to normal, but it would not imply that $X_1$ has normal distribution. We know that the sum of independent normal distributed r.v is again normal distributed. How did you get that the averaged sum has the same distribution as $X_1$?